# Troubleshoot Windows Server 2012 R2 delay

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, delay

I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 on a silent PC with SSD and economy mode, 8 GB RAM.

There are installed:

- MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
- 2 Linux virtual machines, 1 GB RAM each
- File sharing is on
- RDP server is on

Now I encounter a 5-7 sec delay when accessing the server for the first time after idle period. This delay appears on accessing either file shares or MSSQL Server. After that it works fast.

If I access a file share at first and then connect to MSSQL Server, the very first MSSQL request works fast, and vice versa: if I access MSSQL Server at first, the very first file share access works instantly.

I could be connected to MSSQL Server for a long time, and requests are working fast, but when I disconnect and connect again, the first request works with a delay.

Could you provide a guide to troubleshooting?

How to find out whether this delay relates to hardware "economy mode" or not? Or may be to lack of RAM? Or to some other aspects?

Comment: Okay, so is the Server 2012 R2 the host server for the VMs of Linux, file shares, SQL, etc. or what exactly? Does the same happen when accessing the Linux VMs first such as via SSH or is if just the Windows resources? Knowing which OSes and if SQL or the file shares are on the host or other guest VMsmay be helpful as well. Look over the Power Settings on the applicable Windows OSes and the host OS too and be sure those are set to **High performance** for starters maybe. I assume it's not but be sure **Sleep** mode is disabled.

Comment: These are quick thoughts for you to start with since no comments or anything on this for you since yesterday but the **Device Manager** and the Network Adapter(s) **Power Management** tab be sure to *uncheck* to option of **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power** and check all other power settings you can find as well that may have any of the OSes go into some sort of power saving mode or whatever.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT: Thank you for the reply. VMs are responding quickly. The delay concerns only Windows resources.

Comment: Are the Windows resources or correlated OSes tied to a different NIC than the Linux VMs then?

Comment: Pimp Juice: This PC has only one NIC. Recently I've bought a similar PC, but with two NIC, from the same vendor. It has exactly the same software, including VMs, which were cloned by me, and responds always quickly.